# Facebook graph API post on wall weird error

Tags: android

I have problem. I was using  this code:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "this is test");
parameters.putString("description","description test");
parameters.putString("link", "http://www.google.pl");
mFacebook.dialog(ShowFortune.this, "feed", parameters,new SampleDialogListener());
```

and everything was fine, but few days ago "message" parameter stop showing in dialog and on the wall post. "Description" and "link" parameters still working. What I can do to fix this ?  What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook changed API, parameter "message" is now ignored.